# What's the configuration scope in sbt?

Tags: sbt

SBT document NOT give a definition of Configuration scope, document just description the configurations,such as "The configuration concept comes from Ivy","Some configurations you’ll see in sbt: Compile,Test..", that feeling abstract :(
Does someone can help me understand what is configuration scope by simple example.thanks